# No Fixed Frames in RVIZ2 are shown

Tags: ros, ros2, rviz, urdf

I tried to show the URDF of a complex robotic arm in rviz2, but nothing shows in the fixed frames in rviz2, the dropdown menu of fixed frames is empty. I am using ROS2 Humble, with rviz2 (11.2.9). The URDF I have was made from the add-on phobos from Blender, it has a lot of meshes and joints/links. I ran the launch file in a ros package that I built, no errors at all:

```py
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node

import xacro


def generate_launch_description():

    # Check if we're told to use sim time
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')

    # Process the URDF file
    pkg_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ATU_robot_arm'))
    xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_path,'description/urdf','Robot_Arm.urdf')
    robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file)
    
    # Create a robot_state_publisher node
    params = {'robot_description': robot_description_config.toxml(), 'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}
    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[params]
    )


    # Launch!
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='false',
            description='Use sim time if true'),

        node_robot_state_publisher
    ])
```

```
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759318385] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Back_Forearm_Rotation
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759423148] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Back_Forearm_Rotation.000
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759435999] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Backarm_Rotation
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759446894] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Base_Rotation
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759457999] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Base_Rotation.000
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759469313] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Forearm_motor
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759480279] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Gripper
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759491872] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Gripper_Fingers_control
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759502628] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Gripper_Rotation
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759513244] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment backarm_motor
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759523790] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759534127] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_gripper_finger
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759544254] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment new_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759554870] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment new_link.000
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759565626] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment new_link.000.001
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759576451] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment new_link.000.001.002
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759588464] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment new_link.000.001.002.003
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759600128] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment new_link.000.001.002.003.004
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759610604] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment new_link.000.001.002.003.004.005
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759621639] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment new_link.000.001.002.003.004.005.006
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759632045] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment new_link.000.001.002.003.004.005.006.007
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759642591] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment new_link.000.001.002.003.004.005.006.007.008
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702848328.759653627] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_gripper_finger
```